# Ksh script to transfer a file from a server to local machine

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

Looking for a ksh script that could transfer a file from a server to my local machine path. I don't want to transfer it from one server to another server.

I am not good at networking. Do I need to supply my ip address. Any help is appreciated.

I saw that Filezilla (UI s/w application that transfers file from server to local) runs this script in the background

get "name of the file on server" "my local path where I want to transfer"

Comment: Which transfer protocol? SSH?

Comment: SCP or ssh is fine. Also, I connect via putty to these servers.

Answer (score 1):

```
# sftp [[user@]host[:file [file]]]
sftp me@somehost:data/interesting.dat from.somehost.interesting.dat
```

May ask for the password, depending on your ssh setup

Comment: how will it come to my desktop?

Comment: It depends on your setup. File transfer is done with an application from a remote server to where the application runs.

Thus you need a client application running on the machine where your desktop is. Depends on what machine and what applictions are available.

One (best) option FileZilla, running on your local machne connecting to the remote server and transfering files. WinSCP as another option, among tons of others, 

putty is just a  terminal running  commands on a remote server. File transfer would be to that machine.  Why the need for ksh?